# Can I say "I have a girlfriend (a female friend, not a romantic lover)"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Ok, I have a female friend, *can I say "**girlfriend**" as "**a female friend, not a romantic lover**"?*

Ex, **I got married but I have a girlfriend.**

Can I say "**I have a girlfriend** (*a female friend, not a romantic lover*)"?

Also, is "**female friend**" a popular term in everyday conversation?

Comment: [This question was been asked here at least once](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-should-i-refer-to-a-friend-who-is-a-girl-but-not-a-girlfriend)

Comment: (**has** been asked, of course. my bad)

Comment: Are you asking "How do I (a guy) refer idiomatically to a friend who is female in a way that everyone will know that we are not dating or lovers?"

Comment: @TRomano, so, is it very popular to say "*I have a female friend*"?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is, "How does a person, of either sex, refer idiomatically to another person, of either sex, in a way that shows they are not dating or lovers?" the answer is simple

> I have a *good* friend, who ...

or

> I have a *close* friend, who ...

*Close* suggests a friendship of long standing and considerable trust.

Comment: What not use "**female friend**"? is "**female friend**" a popular term in everyday conversation?

Comment: Say what you like, Tom. It seems you want to say the word "female".

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of expressing that. For example, we used to use ***friend-girl*** quite often, and everybody I know understood it (however this is very local and should not be used)

You could also say something like:

> A girl, who is my friend, ........

Or your example:

> I got married but I have a friend, who is a girl.

However, using **but** would look like the fact that you have a friend contradicts the fact that you got married, which wouldn't really make much sense.

Female friend is not a common way of expressing.

Comment: ... I hear "female friend" significantly more often than "friend-girl"... which I have never heard until now. Perhaps it's a regional thing?

Comment: Not everybody. I have never ever heard **friend-girl**.

Comment: @Tromano I meant everybody who i knew, not absolutely everybody. I would say it is very local then.

Comment: Was this is in a place where the speakers were native English speakers, and did they say **friend-girl** and say it unironically?

Comment: @TRomano Speakers were native, and they did say it unirinically with context matching. But it wasnt exactly a native country

Comment: I too have never, ever heard "friend-girl".  I would be very cautious about using that and assuming it will be understood.